# jquery datetime picker date and time should come in box default without clicking on box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime

Hi i have two datetime picker and using jquery 1.7.2 in both the datetime picker i need date and time defaultly  presently am getting these after click box but i need before click only . am using jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/srknthcse/f9raubjp/  thank you for your help

```
$(function() { 
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',

        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d = new Date(); // for now
            datetext=datetext+" "+d.getHours()+": "+d.getMinutes();

            $('#datepicker').val(datetext);
        },
    });
    });
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d1 = new Date();
            var d2 = new Date(d1);
            var addedhour=d2.setHours(d1.getHours()+4);

            // for now
            datetext=datetext+" "+d2.getHours()+": "+d2.getMinutes();
            $('#datepicker1').val(datetext);
        },
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting datepicker to an input field set it to a div.  Then use a hidden input for the value as shown on the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8ztsjcos/2/

```
 <input type="hidden" id="to">  
 <input type="hidden" id="from">

$(function() {
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(datetext){
        var d = new Date(); // for now
        datetext=datetext+" "+d.getHours()+": "+d.getMinutes();
        $('#to').val(datetext);
    },
});
});
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d1 = new Date();
            var d2 = new Date(d1);
            var addedhour=d2.setHours(d1.getHours()+4);

        // for now
        datetext=datetext+" "+d2.getHours()+": "+d2.getMinutes();
        $('#from').val(datetext);
    },
});
});
```

Comment: hi , this snippet is not working please help me exactly where i can put this code thank you

Comment: I've updated the above answer with the correct solution

Comment: hi can how can we modify that to text box only not that pop up

Comment: thank you nick , i have added $document.ready function to get my time on run  and also in to date  i wrote code for disable the dates which are over can you help me please  http://jsfiddle.net/srknthcse/8ztsjcos/9/